# unistore with preact-cli and ssr

Tags: webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering, preact

I am using unistore with preact-cli and it working with --no-prerender option. now I want to SSR of my app but it needs to transpile but i don't know how to write webpack.config only for my server.js and other file remains untouched.

```
const MainAppContainer = require('../src/components/app')
const { Provider } = require('unistore/preact')
const createStore = require('../src/components/store')
const express = require('express');
const { h } = require('preact');
const path = require('path');

const store = createStore(initialState)
            let state = store.getState()
            let body = render(
                            <Provider store={store}>
                                <MainAppContainer url={req.url}/>
                            </Provider>
                        )
            const AppHtml = template.replace(RGX, body);
```

**directory structure**

- build
- src
- server
- template
- package.json

**note**

> project is created by preact-cli with the default template
>   so if i exclude server.js within server folder everything is compiled and run as mentioned in the preact-cli doc.
>   i just want a solution that how to compile server.js
>   **every solution or sugesstion will be appreciated. thanks to all**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render your application from `build/ssr-bundle.js`.